# Java Resetting and copying two dimensional arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I am having trouble resetting a two-dimensional array in java. I have a class that takes in a two-dimentional array. What I am trying to do is copy an existing array, edit that copy, use that copy in an instance of the class, and reset that array to a copy of the original array, all without modifying the original array. If any more information is needed just ask. Thanks in advance!

```
public Iterable<Board> neighbors(){

    Stack<Board> neighbors = new Stack<Board>();

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++){
            if (tiles[i][j] == 0){

                int [][] copy = new int[N][N];
                System.arraycopy(tiles, 0, copy, 0, tiles.length);

                if (i != 0){
                    exch(copy, i, j, i - 1, j);
                    neighbors.push(new Board(copy));
                    copy = null;
                    System.arraycopy(tiles, 0, copy, 0, tiles.length);
                }
                if (i <= N - 2){
                    exch(copy, i, j, i + 1, j);
                    neighbors.push(new Board(copy));
                    copy = null;
                    System.arraycopy(tiles, 0, copy, 0, tiles.length);
                }
                if (j != 0){
                    exch(copy, i, j, i, j - 1);
                    neighbors.push(new Board(copy));
                    copy = null;
                    System.arraycopy(tiles, 0, copy, 0, tiles.length);
                }
                if (j <= N - 2){
                    exch(copy, i, j, i, j + 1);
                    neighbors.push(new Board(copy));
                    copy = null;
                    System.arraycopy(tiles, 0, copy, 0, tiles.length);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return neighbors;

}
```

I changed my code to that shown above but i got this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
at Board.neighbors(Board.java:74)
at Board.main(Board.java:136)
```

Comment: "I am having trouble..." can we see your code which will let us reproduce your problem?

Comment: @Pshemo if you need anything else just holla

Comment: `int [][] copy = tiles;` doesn't create copy of array. It just create another reference for same array. You need to implement your own method which will create new array and fill it with content of old array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that in Java multidimensional arrays are actually arrays referencing other arrays. Internally an array in Java can only have a single dimension.

To copy the content of an array, you can use the [`System.arraycopy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int))() method. Note that for multidimensional arrays this will only copy the top-level array's references to the same inner arrays, so things are a little more complicated:

```
int[][] copy = new int[original.length][]; // new top-level array of same size
for (int i = 0; i < copy.length; i++) {
    copy[i] = new int[original[i].length]; // new inner array of same size
    System.arraycopy(original[i], 0, copy[i], 0, original[i].length); // copy values
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> int [][] copy = tiles;
> ```

This is not how you make a copy of an Array , in the above mentioned code `copy` is just another reference to `tiles Array` Object .

Use [System.arraycopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29)

```
int[] src  = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
int[] dest = new int[5];

System.arraycopy( src, 0, dest, 0, src.length );
```

Here if you even change `src` , `dest` will remain the same

Comment: Note that Java doesn't actually have multidimensional arrays, but arrays of arrays. If you make a copy of the top-level array, it will reference the same inner array objects as the original top-level array.

Comment: `arraycopy` doesn't create "deep" copies. Sure, the array will look like a copy, but if you modify a value in the original array, it will also change in the copy, because they actually use the very same inner array objects.

Comment: @NeerajJain I deleted my comment long before your response. I did it since Wormbo explained what I wanted to say better. Also why do you think I down-voted your answer?

Comment: @Pshemo , just got your comment after downvoted notification so thought so , removing the comment

Comment: I can easily prove my innocence if you want :). Anyway claiming that your solution will work regardless if array is multidimensional or not is wrong. Take a look at this example: http://ideone.com/flzeki. Despite reading both times array from `src` reference I was able to edit its content via `dest` reference. I happened because top level array contain references to arrays representing its rows, so this way we created two arrays which share same rows. What OP needs is deep-copy, what your solution gave was shallow-copy.

Comment: yeah i got that explaination from @Wormbo thats why upvoted his answer :)